# thread not running at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created the following class for ant based pathfinding (I know horrible idea but still)...

```
public class main implements Runnable{
    static int[][] maze;
    static int[] targets;
    int treadnumber;
    public main(int i){
        treadnumber=i;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        maze=mazeReader.read();
        colony.createscent(maze);   
        targets =targetReader.read();

        //number of running ants
        for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
            Thread a= new Thread(new main(i));
            a.run();
        }
        System.out.println("test");

        System.out.println("and the winner is:");
        System.out.println(colony.bestroute);
        System.out.println(colony.lengthbest/2);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<100 ;i++){
            System.out.println(treadnumber);
        maze =mazeReader.read();
        ant a = new ant();
        a.loadmaze(maze.clone());
        a.start(targets.clone());
        }
    }


}
```

For effiency reasons this should run multi treaded however when I let them print the threadnumber I get a neat little ordended set of 100 0's followed by 100 1's ext. This whole code takes around 30 seconds to execute so they should run at least somewhat parallel. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is about invoking `run` method instead of starting thread.

Change

```
a.run();
```

to

```
a.start();
```

---

When you invoke run method, it executes the run without starting the thread process, without a scheduled call.

In order to lead the jvm to schedule your threads, you have to use start method.

Comment: And- calling a.run() is like overriding i.e, calling any other method. a.start() performs some internal magic (don't bother about it now) and starts the execution of a thread. run() only contains what is to be done by the thread. start() makes running possible by calling run() internally.

Answer (score 2):

At `// number of running ants` loop replace `a.run();` with `a.start();`